# How do I overwrite a BigQuery table (data and schema) from PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a PySpark `DataFrame` to a BigQuery table. The schema for this table may change between job executions (columns may be added or omitted). So, I would like to overwrite this table each execution.

An example:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[(1, "A")],schema=["col1","col2"])
df.write.format("bigquery")\
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket","temporary-bucket-name")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save(path="dataset_name.table_name")
```

When `dataset_name.table_name" doesn't already exists, the above works great to generate:
[image]

However, subsequent jobs may be as below:

```
df.withColumnRenamed("col1", "col3").write.format("bigquery")\
    .option("writeDisposition", "WRITE_TRUNCATE")\
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket","temporary-bucket-name")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save(path="dataset_name.table_name")
```

The above job does not generate what I want. I get no `col3` and `col1` still appears:
[image]

Even more disturbing, I get no error message.

So, what options should I specify so that the result in BigQuery is just `col2` and `col3` with appropriate data?

Basically, I want to mimic the SQL statement `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` from PySpark.

Comment: Just to get a better understanding, are you aiming to move all data in BQ from Col1 to Col3 when renaming is needed or does Col1 not exist sometimes and the past data from it it's not relevant?

Comment: The second. Col1 may not exist in a future load job, and its data is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic, Col1 does not exist sometimes and the past data from the table is irrelevant.

You could approach by deleting the table with dynamic schema prior to writing to it, therefore avoiding any schema conflicts:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 

client = bigquery.Client()
client.delete_table(table=project_id.dataset_id.table_id, not_found_ok=True)

df.write.format("bigquery") \
  .option("createDisposition", "CREATE_IF_NEEDED") \
  .......
```

Keep in mind the Pyspark flag `createDisposition` creates a new table if it doesn't exist, and it's set to `CREATE_IF_NEEDED` by default, so it doesn't need to be explicit.

Comment: This is a possibility we looked at, but if the load job fails, then the table doesn't exist. We're really looking to update the data in the table for dependent jobs, and while previous data would be invalidated, it's important that, if the load job fails, the old data and table are still there.

Comment: What about, loading first into a tmp_table to make sure the "load job" runs? Then once you confirm the tmp_table is loaded, you can either copy truncate to prod if there weren't schema changes or drop prod table in favor of new tmp_table (so you copy and create the new prod in this case)